# Phantomjs node module install for Phantomjs2.0

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, karma-runner, node-modules

I do have a PhantomJS 2.0 installed and running on machine.
whenever I try to install karma-phantomjs-launcher.
I am ending with following error

```
$npm install 
npm WARN package.json karma-tap@1.0.3 No repository field.
phantomjs@1.9.19 install /root/ravi/strongloop/request/request/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs
node install.js
Found PhantomJS at /bin/phantomjs ...verifying
PhantomJS detected, but wrong version 2.0.0 @ /bin/phantomjs.
npm ERR! phantomjs@1.9.19 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.19 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Is their any way to start working with karma-phantomjs-launcher with existing PhantomJS2.0 .